# Why arithmetic does not end up with s?

Tags: etymology, orthography

Usually disciplines end up with s: mathematics, ballistics, genetics, gymnastics, linguistics, logistics, optics, politics, semantics, statistics, etc.

A simple question: why did arithmetic not end up with s?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't “astronomy” end with an “s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422233/why-doesnt-astronomy-end-with-an-s) The accepted answer in the link is the same as the answer given below by user 66974.

Comment: @Justin It does, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by the following extract from Etymonline, only the disciplines that got their names after the 16th century ended with an s because of the classical custom trend of using neutral  plural of adjectives in the fashion of Greek -ikos.

***[-ics](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ics?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***:

> in the names of sciences or disciplines (acoustics, aerobics, economics, etc.), a 16c. revival of the classical custom of using the neuter plural of adjectives with Greek -ikos "pertaining to" to mean "matters relevant to" and also as the titles of treatises about them.
>
> ***Subject matters that acquired their English names before c. 1500, however, tend to be singular in form*** (arithmetic, logic, magic, music, rhetoric).

Comment: I can't upvote duplicate answers to exact duplicates.